# Como criar metodo para printar um relatorio - java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, relatório

Como crio um metodo para printar um relatorio do DB. Segue meu metodo abaixo.

```
public void printReport (Date initialDate, Date endDate){

        list<Sale> sales = getSales (initialDate, endDate);

        for (Sale s:sales){

            Store st = s.getStore(); // Recura a Loja

            CreditCard cc = s.getCreditCard(); // Recupera o Cartão

            System.out.println(st.getNome() + ";" + cc.getName() + s.getValue());
        }
}
```

Comment: Print em que IReport ? Que tipo de relatório É? Aplicação Web ou DESKTOP ?

Comment: faça o tour da comunidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e marque as outras questões que você já fez como respondida

Comment: É um print simples, de execute a query do banco, sem usar frameworks. É em DESKTOP.  Segue enunciado: -- Construa um código para printar o relatório. Considere que os modelos Sale,
CreditCard e Store contém os atributos e relacionamentos que representam as colunas
das tabelas. O código receberá como parâmetro as datas para geração do relatório.
Considere também que já existe o método getSales(initialDate, endDate), que irá executar
a query elaborada na questão 1.
public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {
List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);
...
}

Comment: Seu método está ok, Qual é sua duvida ?

Comment: Minha dúvida é se preciso colocar isso em uma classe DAO.
Mas pelo enunciado acho que nao, só estao pedindo o metodo mesmo. o/